# Zip file not getting updated completely

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I need assistance finding the bug in following code. The code is meant to create a zip file, out different batch of files. The process of creating zip is and should be asynchronous. So, the method which creates zip is running concurrently (with different batch of files). If you notice method `SingleZipFile` there is `Console.ReadKey()`, so it waits until a key is pressed (basically it halts the process), this way I get the desired result and I get a complete zip file, produced from concurrently running methods.
However, if `Console.ReadKey()` is commented, I get incomplete or overwritten zip file with only one batch of files. What's the issue here?

**Code:**

```
public static async Task SplitDir(string zipFileName, List<List<FileInfo>> pdfFilesBatch)
{

    FileStream fs = File.Create(zipFileName);
    fs.Close();

    foreach (var batch in pdfFilesBatch)
        tasks.Add(NewCreateZipAsync(zipFileName, batch));

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

public static Task NewCreateZipAsync(string zipFileName, List<FileInfo> filesToZip)
{
    Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        SingleZipFile(zipFileName, filesToZip);
    });
    return task;
}

public static void SingleZipFile(string zipFileName, List<FileInfo> filesToZip)
{
    Console.ReadKey();
    using FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream(zipFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    using (ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
    {
        foreach (var file in filesToZip)
            zipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile(file.FullName, file.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't have multiple threads modifying the same zip file unless you use a library specifically built to allow this. Otherwise you'll corrupt the file. A ZIP file contains a directory of entries with its contents, paths etc. When you add a file to the package, you also modify that directory. Trying to modify a ZIP from multiple threads will corrupt that directory *at least*.

Comment: `The process of creating zip is and should be asynchronous.` no it's not. Putting `Task.Run`  (Task.Factory.StartNew is obsolete) around a blocking method runs it in the background, it doesn't make it asynchronous

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos with that said, what should replace `Task.Factory.StartNew`  is it `Task.Run`? Like I mentioned when I halt the process using `Console.ReadKey()`, everything is fine but obviously this won't be there in real life. Do you know any library which can do this?

Comment: The `Task.Run` is preferable in general. [This](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/ "Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew") article explains their differences in detail. But you should use [neither](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/ "Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?") of these for creating asynchronous wrappers of synchronous methods.

Comment: `ZipArchive` is not thread-safe, you can't modify the zip file in parallel with this class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, none of this needs async/await.   If you need to call SplitDir with different parameters, but the actual creation is synchronous, just return Task.CompletedTask;

```
public static Task SplitDir(string zipFileName, List<List<FileInfo>> pdfFilesBatch)
{

  FileStream fs = File.Create(zipFileName);
  fs.Close();

  foreach (var batch in pdfFilesBatch)
     NewCreateZip(zipFileName, batch);

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

public static void NewCreateZip(string zipFileName, List<FileInfo> filesToZip)
{
    SingleZipFile(zipFileName, filesToZip);
 }

public static void SingleZipFile(string zipFileName, List<FileInfo> filesToZip)
{
    using FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream(zipFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    using (ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
    {
     foreach (var file in filesToZip)
        zipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile(file.FullName, file.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's superb. What what the mistake?

Comment: @Aniruddha if you accept this, it means you didn't want to process files in parallel at all. This `SplitDir` will run synchronously. You might as well remove `return Task.CompletedTask` and change the return type to `void`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, yes I see that it's running synchronously. What's the way to run this asynchronously? Why it can't this job be done asynchronously, if yes how and if not then why not? I'm of the belief that there should be some way to achieve this asynchronously. Or do I need to resort to some other language?

Comment: Also, my other question is how same can be achieved using `MemoryStream`?

Comment: This has been answered already. Not with this class, no matter where the file is stored

Comment: You can call `SplitDir` many times asynchronously, you just can't process the files into the same zip asynchronously.

Comment: @Neil Thanks for the info